# htaccess не реагирует на robots.txt

Tags: .htaccess, robots.txt

Есть поддомены, например, site.ru и dev.site.ru
Все они направлены на одну папку, т.е какой домен не открой будет выводится один сайт.

Нужно при запросе dev.site.ru/robots.txt перенаправлять запрос на dev.site.ru/robots_dev.txt

Писал следующее:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z-_0-9]+)\.site\.ru
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/robots.txt$
#RewriteRule (.*) robots_%1.txt [R=301,L]
```

Но при заходе на dev.site.ru/robots.txt всё равно выводит обычный robots.txt

Подскажите что нужно сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если веб-сервер apache, то включите опцию AllowOverride (заменив None на All) у виртуального хоста.